# What are the effects of heating paraffin wax above it's melting point

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I'm working with a paraffin embedding station that we recently learned was overshooting it's set point (60C) and heating paraffin to 100C. The problem has been corrected, but I'm curious what the mechanical/physical effects of paraffin being heated to almost twice the melting point. This is for a microtome setup (slicing at 5 microns) so micro features can and would be effected.

Comment: The mechanical effects on the paraffin? Or on the apparatus generally? Also, could you explain in more detail how the apparatus works? I've never worked with one; the phase "paraffin embedding station" gives me a hazy idea of what it does, but more detail would be greatly helpful.

Comment: The paraffin is inserted as paraffin chips (solid at room temperature)  heated to a set point, and melted via a heating element. The melted paraffin comes out of a nozzle. The cassettes, molds, and sample are then doused with the liquid paraffin, then cooled until they can be separated. (looks like this  http://drp8p5tqcb2p5.cloudfront.net/uploads/tx_templavoila/1029219956.jpg

Comment: the effects on the paraffin*

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** A brief heating to 100 C (instead to 60 C) probably did not destroy your paraffin.

It is not too surprising the paraffin accidentally was warmed to 100 C, instead to 60 C. Especially in the solid state it does conduct heat not very well, and has a considerable heat capacity, too.  If it melts around 60 C,  heating to 100 C won't lead to vigorous boiling (like boiling water at this temperature).  In addition, I assume once you noticed the temperature higher than necessary / suitable for the embedding, you rapidly down-regulated the heater, too.

Maybe the manufacturer of the paraffin provided some properties of the batch delivered to you, beside melting point an indication of the decomposition temperature, too; which however should be *much* higher than 100 C (say 150...175 C).  I think it is unlikely that you observed fumes similar to the ones by an overheated frying pan, which were indicative for decomposition of the paraffin.

The reasoning: Many of the contemporary candles are equally made of paraffin, and when the children make new ones, chunks of old candles and new paraffin are equally thrown into the same melting pot, surrounded by (gently) boiling water, too. And while they do so for hours, I still have to see one new candle that became brown or black because the vessel was heated for so long time.